# Issues align div for html email

Tags: html, css

I've been reviewing some older posts on how to align two divs side by side, however I just can't seem to get this right.  I have a HTML email which I would like to send with two buttons 'Accept' and 'Reject' Code I'm been testing is below.

```css
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <style> #buttonGroup {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#acceptButton {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
#rejectButton {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
</style> </head> <body> <div id=buttonGroup> <div id="acceptButton"> <p align="center"><!--[if mso]> <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="{!$Label.Site_URL_Prefix}campaignAccept?leadid={!CampaignMember.LeadId}{!Lead.Id}&contactid={!CampaignMember.ContactId}{!Contact.Id}&campaignId={!Campaign.Id}&action=Accept" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="13%" strokecolor="#31b934" fillcolor="#2c772e"> <w:anchorlock/> <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Accept</center> </v:roundrect> <![endif]--><a href="{!$Label.Site_URL_Prefix}campaignAccept?leadid={!CampaignMember.LeadId}{!Lead.Id}&contactid={!CampaignMember.ContactId}{!Contact.Id}&campaignId={!Campaign.Id}&action=Accept" style="background-color:#31b934;border:1px solid #2c772e;border-radius:5px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:200px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Accept</a></p> </div> <div id="rejectButton>
<p align="center"><!--[if mso]> <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="{!$Label.Site_URL_Prefix}campaign?leadid={!CampaignMember.LeadId}{!Lead.Id}&contactid={!CampaignMember.ContactId}{!Contact.Id}&campaignId={!Campaign.Id}&action=Reject" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="13%" strokecolor="#d12835" fillcolor="#921620"> <w:anchorlock/> <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Decline</center> </v:roundrect> <![endif]--><a href="{!$Label.Site_URL_Prefix}campaign?leadid={!CampaignMember.LeadId}{!Lead.Id}&contactid={!CampaignMember.ContactId}{!Contact.Id}&campaignId={!Campaign.Id}&action=Reject" style="background-color:#d12835;border:1px solid #921620;border-radius:5px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:200px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Decline</a></p> </div> </div> </body> </html>
```

I've provide the result I'm getting, you can see that they are just not lining up correct, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forget double quote for `#rejectButton`

```css
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <style> #buttonGroup {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#acceptButton {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
#rejectButton {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
</style> </head> <body> <div id=buttonGroup> <div id="acceptButton"> <p align="center"><!--[if mso]> <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="{!$Label.Site_URL_Prefix}campaignAccept?leadid={!CampaignMember.LeadId}{!Lead.Id}&contactid={!CampaignMember.ContactId}{!Contact.Id}&campaignId={!Campaign.Id}&action=Accept" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="13%" strokecolor="#31b934" fillcolor="#2c772e"> <w:anchorlock/> <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Accept</center> </v:roundrect> <![endif]--><a href="{!$Label.Site_URL_Prefix}campaignAccept?leadid={!CampaignMember.LeadId}{!Lead.Id}&contactid={!CampaignMember.ContactId}{!Contact.Id}&campaignId={!Campaign.Id}&action=Accept" style="background-color:#31b934;border:1px solid #2c772e;border-radius:5px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:200px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Accept</a></p> </div> <div id="rejectButton">
<p align="center"><!--[if mso]> <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="{!$Label.Site_URL_Prefix}campaign?leadid={!CampaignMember.LeadId}{!Lead.Id}&contactid={!CampaignMember.ContactId}{!Contact.Id}&campaignId={!Campaign.Id}&action=Reject" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="13%" strokecolor="#d12835" fillcolor="#921620"> <w:anchorlock/> <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Decline</center> </v:roundrect> <![endif]--><a href="{!$Label.Site_URL_Prefix}campaign?leadid={!CampaignMember.LeadId}{!Lead.Id}&contactid={!CampaignMember.ContactId}{!Contact.Id}&campaignId={!Campaign.Id}&action=Reject" style="background-color:#d12835;border:1px solid #921620;border-radius:5px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:200px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Decline</a></p> </div> </div> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Thanks all for the comments, it seems to always be the little things.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a " after the div id attribute rejectButton.

Answer (score 0):

As noticed, Accept button is inside a div and within that div it is having a `<p>` tag.

`<p>` is having margin due to which alignments are going wrong.

Either add `<p>` tag to decline as well or remove margin from `<p>` tag.

Like

```
#acceptButton p
{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o65uvst6/)

Hope this Helps.

-Help :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to focus more on the code the problem was errors on write the id's

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <style> #buttonGroup {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#acceptButton {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
#rejectButton {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
</style> </head> <body> <div id="buttonGroup"> <div id="acceptButton"> <p align="center"><!--[if mso]> <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="{!$Label.Site_URL_Prefix}campaignAccept?leadid={!CampaignMember.LeadId}{!Lead.Id}&contactid={!CampaignMember.ContactId}{!Contact.Id}&campaignId={!Campaign.Id}&action=Accept" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="13%" strokecolor="#31b934" fillcolor="#2c772e"> <w:anchorlock/> <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Accept</center> </v:roundrect> <![endif]--><a href="{!$Label.Site_URL_Prefix}campaignAccept?leadid={!CampaignMember.LeadId}{!Lead.Id}&contactid={!CampaignMember.ContactId}{!Contact.Id}&campaignId={!Campaign.Id}&action=Accept" style="background-color:#31b934;border:1px solid #2c772e;border-radius:5px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:200px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Accept</a></p> </div> <div id="rejectButton">
<p align="center"><!--[if mso]> <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="{!$Label.Site_URL_Prefix}campaign?leadid={!CampaignMember.LeadId}{!Lead.Id}&contactid={!CampaignMember.ContactId}{!Contact.Id}&campaignId={!Campaign.Id}&action=Reject" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="13%" strokecolor="#d12835" fillcolor="#921620"> <w:anchorlock/> <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Decline</center> </v:roundrect> <![endif]--><a href="{!$Label.Site_URL_Prefix}campaign?leadid={!CampaignMember.LeadId}{!Lead.Id}&contactid={!CampaignMember.ContactId}{!Contact.Id}&campaignId={!Campaign.Id}&action=Reject" style="background-color:#d12835;border:1px solid #921620;border-radius:5px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:200px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Decline</a></p> </div> </div> </body> </html>
```